# Oracle ADF 11g - passing a pdf to a print queue

Tags: java, oracle, pdf, oracle11g

I have a page of pdf reports with view and download button. The users have asked if the pdf could be sent to a printer without having to open each pdf individually?
The reports are iterated over a jsf page and I have added a selectBooleanCheckBox to mark which pdf to print. A bit of code from the reports page:

```
</af:panelGroupLayout>
   <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl10" styleClass="itemAction" inlineStyle="padding:10.0px;">
        <af:goLink styleClass="directoryLink" id="viewLink"
            rendered="#{!empty attrs.item.viewUrl}"
            destination="#{attrs.item.viewUrl}"
            targetFrame="_blank"
            disabled="false">
            <af:outputLabel id="view-icon" styleClass="viewButton directoryHoverButton"/>
            <af:outputText id="view-label" styleClass="directoryButtonLabel" value="#{res['button.view']}"/>
        </af:goLink>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl11" styleClass="itemAction" inlineStyle="padding:10.0px;">
        <af:goLink id="downloadLink" destination="#{attrs.item.downloadURL}" styleClass="directoryLink" disabled="false">
        <af:outputLabel id="download-icon" styleClass="downloadButton directoryHoverButton"/>
        <af:outputText id="download-label"
            styleClass="directoryButtonLabel"
            value="#{res['button.download']}"/>
        </af:goLink>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl12" styleClass="itemAction" inlineStyle="padding:10px; vertical-align:bottom;">
        <af:selectBooleanCheckbox id="dc_sbc1"
            autoSubmit="true"
            partialTriggers="dc_sbc1"
            valueChangeListener="#{viewScope.printingBean.printerCheckboxListener}">
        </af:selectBooleanCheckbox>
   <af:outputText id="print-label" styleClass="directoryButtonLabel"  value="Add"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

So my question is how can I pass the pdf from the download link to a print queue using the ValueChangeListener (or if there a better way)?

Thanks

David